# Worldwide programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages

I'm in the USA, and essentially only have visibility to coding languages in typical use in my USA-based business.  These are primarily C++, C#, and Java.  **Are these languages that are common here also ones that are commonly used world-wide?**  To help narrow down the question, I am mostly curious about the former USSR countries that have (or had at recent times) a similar technical programming prowess to what can be attributed to programming abilities in the USA.  Just wondering if programming languages can be considered universal languages, or, like spoken/written communication languages, are region or country-specific.

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: @gnat, this is an interesting and potentially useful question though, in my view. Can you suggest a way of editing it so it doesn't just become a "list of things" question?

Comment: Related: [programming languages used in the Soviet Union's space program](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/145669/what-software-programming-languages-were-used-by-the-soviet-unions-space-progra) (likely not currently used, so it's not a dupe)

Comment: Wow, apparently [DRAKON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON) (a continuation of the software used by the USSR's Buran space program) is still available. Though now it seems to be a CASE/flowchart-based frontend for mainstream languages such as Java or C++.

Comment: All of today's common languages aside from C, C++, and shell were developed or came into prominence *after* the dissolution of the Soviet Union. There are languages from non-western, non-English-speaking countries, but none of those have a comparably large ecosystem. An interesting (though non-USSR) example is Ruby, which was developed in Japan and had a mostly Japanese ecosystem during its early years.

Comment: @amon Nothing can touch C/C++/Java, etc, I suppose, but the French do some interesting work in languages used within and without academia, such as Prolog and OCaml (which is [big in academia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INRIA) but also [used in the trading industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jane_Street_Capital)). They don't even register in the radar compared to Java, of course.

Comment: Distribution of languages is more business-oriented than country-oriented. For instance, Prolog has been designed for Artificial Intelligence, not for French developers.

Comment: @amon Python, Perl, Objective-C, Object Pascal, and MATLAB are all in TIOBE's top 20 for December 2016, and all have releases predating the USSR's dissolution. (Assembly too, but that's a collection of languages.) Of course, of those, only Python originated from outside the U.S. (Netherlands), and its release only preceded the end of the USSR by a few months.